# Flicker screen effect

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, effects

I am using blender as a video editing software. And I wanted to know i it is possible to get this effect from it -->  https://youtu.be/BXbBTTmdYtA?t=65

The effect causes a flickering screen can this be done by inserting black frames?

Comment: Exactly what kind of effect are you trying to reproduce? I can't tell from just watching the video in the link.

Comment: @brasshat I think it's the strobe effect (the flickering). Should be pretty simple to do in the VSE.

Comment: See http://blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/effects.html The image of the _add_-effect it very similar to the effect  you want try _subtract_ instead.

Comment: I've voting to reopen this, because I think the only possible effect the OP could be talking about here is the flickering effect. I think this is a case where the actual text doesn't tell much, but the links tell all that is needed.

Comment: @TARDISMaker After watching the video I saw several effects which I thought the OP could potentially be referring to. If you feel you know what the OP is saying, then feel free to answer (I've reopened it now since stacker has mentioned the strobe effect in the question, albeit without confirmation from the OP)

Answer (score 2):

The **flickering effect** can be achieved by adding an **effect strip on top** of the movie clip.

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Effect Strip > Color
2. Go to the *Properties Panel* of the video sequence editor (<kbd>N</kbd>)
3. Set the blendtype to *Alpha Over*
4. Set a keyframe on the opacity (also in *Properties Panel*) by clicking on <kbd>I</kbd>
5. Go to the graph editor and add a *Noise Modifier* (in the *Properties Panel* of the graph editor)
6. Tweak the different options in the *Noise Editor* like scaling, strength, phase the frame range etc.

[image]

Comment: I think this would have too much of a fall off. Yes, it would work, but it would be a different effect than the one in the video.